# Where to add DISTINCT to SQL subquery

Tags: sql

I want to select unique images from a database. I am using the following query which includes a specific image, `(ID=11)`, but I'm getting some repeated images:

```
$photo=mysql_query("SELECT A. * FROM (
SELECT * FROM profile_images
WHERE approved='N'  
ORDER BY (ID = 11) DESC, RAND()      
LIMIT $sn) 
as A ORDER BY RAND()");
```

Where can I put `DISTINCT`? I have tried:

```
$photo=mysql_query("SELECT A. * FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT FROM profile_images
WHERE approved='N'  
ORDER BY (ID = 11) DESC, RAND()      
LIMIT $sn) 
as A ORDER BY RAND()");
```

But I'm getting this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM profile_images WHERE approved='N' ORDER BY (ID = 11) DESC, RAND(' at line 2

Comment: It doesn't look like you are specifying a column with DISTINCT (SELECT DISTINCT column_name)

Comment: You lost * when adding distinct, it should be __distinct *__.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `DISTINCT` but you are not selecting any columns in your sub-query.  You have to add the columns you want or `select *`

change you current query from this:

```
$photo=mysql_query("SELECT A. * FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT FROM profile_images
WHERE approved='N'  
ORDER BY (ID = 11) DESC, RAND()      
LIMIT $sn) 
as A ORDER BY RAND()");
```

to this:

```
$photo=mysql_query("SELECT A. * FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM profile_images
WHERE approved='N'  
ORDER BY (ID = 11) DESC, RAND()      
LIMIT $sn) 
as A ORDER BY RAND()");
```

Comment: if it worked for you, be sure to select it as the accepted answer by clicking the checkmark.

Answer (score 3):

You're missing *what* to select distinct - just add a star `*`:

```
...
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM profile_images
...
```